# Why is 'eval-after-load' required here?

Tags: init-file, dired, keymap, variables, eval-after-load

```
(eval-after-load "dired" 
  '(progn
     (define-key dired-mode-map "c" 'dired-create-empty-file)
     (define-key dired-mode-map "r" 'dired-do-compress-to)))
```

Why is the `eval-after-load` necessary when this is an init file? From my understanding, it makes it only run when `dired` is loaded, but isn't the init file also loaded once? I was getting "symbol's value as variable is void" warning for `dired-mode-map` but it was working fine without.

Is this because the warning is emitted before `dired` is loaded, but the symbol is resolved by the time emacs is started up?

Comment: I believe you may have edited it to be that way, from the history.

Comment: Oh sorry, I copied your code to my Emacs to format it.  Perhaps I deleted a word by mistake and rewrote it. Sorry again.

Comment: Ah. I actually had that formatted from emacs. Strange. I have `indent-tabs-mode` off with the `tab-width 4`.

Comment: Note that you should prefer the macro `with-eval-after-load` over `eval-after-load`. If you look at its code, you'll see that `with-eval-after-load`  avoids explicit quoting by using `lambda`. Maybe, that does not play such a great role for the init file which is usually not byte-compiled but for byte-compiled library files, explicitly quoted sexps are not byte-compiled, but lambda-expressions (and sharp-quoted expressions) are. There is more (also about lexical scoping) at https://discourse.doomemacs.org/t/why-are-some-function-symbols-sharp-quoted/125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isn't the init file also loaded once?

Yes, it is loaded once.  Loaded when you launch Emacs.

See <https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html>.

> Why is the eval-after-load necessary when this is an init file?

To make sure that before executing the following code:

```lisp
(progn
  (define-key dired-mode-map "c" 'dired-create-empty-file)
  (define-key dired-mode-map "r" 'dired-do-compress-to))
```

variable `dired-mode-map` has already been defined / set with a value,
IOW, to avoid

> "symbol's value as variable is void"

After `"dired"` is loaded, `dired-mode-map` will get its own value.
Since *you don't know* when `dired` will be loaded, use `eval-after-load` is a good choice.

Comment: I see, but since this is in `init` and `dired` will always be loaded by the time I'm typing, it's not incorrect, but it gets a warning since the variable is not defined yet

Comment: @user129393192: What do you mean by "*`dired` will always be loaded by the time I'm typing*"?

Comment: I mean that wrapping it like this only avoids the warning, but functionality would not be affected ,since the symbol is resolved, by the time I am typing.

Comment: @user129393192: What do you mean by "*the symbol is resolved*"? Variable `dired-mode-map` is defined in package `dired` and it is initialized only when Emacs loads that package.

Comment: Yes exactly. I was just saying that by the time I am typing that that package will be loaded, so that's why there was no issues with me using it without `eval-after-load` in my init.file, except for the warning.

Comment: @user129393192: "*by the time I am typing that that package will be loaded*" -- Why? Is this a behavior defined in documentation? |||| "*except for the warning.*" -- My Emacs just signals an **error** if I don't write `eval-after-load` unless it `require`s `dired` somehow. I think your Emacs `require`s `dired` in *other* way instead of your typing. Anyway, if you know less about ELisp, use `eval-after-load` please.

Comment: I have, I was just curious how it didn't seem to be required.

Comment: You stated explicitly in your question "I was getting "symbol's value as variable is void" warning for dired-mode-map" which is clear evidence that dired has not yet been loaded at the point in time that this code in your init file is evaluated.  Which is normal -- dired is not a standard pre-loaded library.  So why are you saying "it didn't seem to be required" when you are getting that error?  Clearly it *is* required.  The only reason it might not be is if something *earlier* in your init file was already loading dired (but if that was the case, you would not see the error).